# Rust trait state

Tags: struct, rust, code-duplication, traits

I'll start with this monster "Monster" code from [Rust for Rubyist](http://www.rustforrubyists.com/book/chapter-10.html):

```
trait Monster {
    fn attack(&self);
    fn new() -> Self;
}

struct IndustrialRaverMonkey {
    life: int,
    strength: int,
    charisma: int,
    weapon: int,
}

struct DwarvenAngel {
    life: int,
    strength: int,
    charisma: int,
    weapon: int,
} ...
impl Monster for IndustrialRaverMonkey { ...
impl Monster for DwarvenAngel { ...
```

I worry about duplication of code. In Java I would create interface that define `attack` method and base class with all that parameters (`life`, `strength`, `charisma`, `weapon`). I will do same thing in C++ with abstract class.
I can find some ugly and unintuitive ways to work around this problem, but is there a good way to reduce code? I mean, to keep it scalable and readable.

Answer (score 4):

Another approach, which favors composition, and from which is easier to diverge implementations if needed (e.g., the `Characteristics` for `DwarvenAngel` require an additional field):

```
trait Monster {
    fn attack(&self);
}

struct Characteristics {
    life: int,
    strength: int,
    charisma: int,
    weapon: int,
}

struct IndustrialRaverMonkey {
    characteristics: Characteristics
}

struct DwarvenAngel {
    characteristics: Characteristics
}

fn same_attack(c: Characteristics) {
    fail!("not implemented")
}

impl Monster for IndustrialRaverMonkey {
    fn attack(&self) {
        same_attack(self.characteristics)
    }
}

impl Monster for DwarvenAngel {
    fn attack(&self) {
        same_attack(self.characteristics)
    }
}
```

Or, you can have an enum represent your monster types, very similar to A.B.'s answer:

```
trait Monster {
    fn attack(&self);
}

struct Characteristics {
    life: int,
    strength: int,
    charisma: int,
    weapon: int,
}

enum Monsters {
    IndustrialRaverMonkey(Characteristics),
    DwarvenAngel(Characteristics),
}

fn same_attack(_: &Characteristics) {
    fail!("not implemented")
}

impl Monster for Monsters {
    fn attack(&self) {
        match *self {
            IndustrialRaverMonkey(ref c) => same_attack(c),
            DwarvenAngel(ref c)          => same_attack(c)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Out of interest, why `~Characteristics` in the structs, rather than just `Characteristics`? (The latter is recommmended, there's rarely a need to heap allocating (small) structs with `~`.)

Comment: @dbaupp I'm still a noob when it comes to pointers actually. You're right, that's a small struct. I'll amend my answer. Any other suggestions are welcome.

Comment: As I understand, I have to implement dispatching myself... That's interesting, I'm rustnoob and thought that there are some other mistical mechanisms.

Comment: @IvanIvanov, there are currently several RFCs which propose some kind of virtual dispatch, which turned out to be needed sometimes for space efficiency (e.g. DOM tree in a browser engine). So it is possible that there *will* be some kind of "mystical mechanism" in future :)

Answer (score 2):

Would you consider something like this an acceptable solution?

```
trait Actor {
    fn attack(&self);
}

enum MonsterId {
    IndustrialRaverMonkey,
    DwarvenAngel
}

struct Monster {
    life: int,
    strength: int
}

impl Monster {
    fn new(id: MonsterId) -> Monster {
        match id {
            IndustrialRaverMonkey => 
            Monster { life: 12, strength: 8 },

            DwarvenAngel => 
            Monster { life: 18, strength: 12 }
        }
    }
}


impl Actor for Monster { 
    fn attack(&self) {}
}
```

Updated with a better example.